# Selenium cant find element? (automated web app)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web

Ive tried xpath, name , id but not sure why it wont work. Every time i try , it just says that it cannot find the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/mattcasey/Desktop/SPLASHFORCE/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/MyAccount-Register")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)
first_name_field = driver.find_element_by_name("profile_customer_firstname")
first_name_field.send_keys("Test")
```

Comment: Well, copy-pasting your URL returned `URL not found` site, so please check if you have right address.

Comment: Its the way this site is formatting it with a space, "https://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/MyAccount-Register" Is the site and selenium loads the site fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you search for has `id` attribute with `profile_customer_firstname` value, but not `name`, so you should use

```
first_name_field = driver.find_element_by_id("profile_customer_firstname")
```

Also it is located inside an `iframe`. Try:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='sso-iframe']"))
first_name_field = driver.find_element_by_id("profile_customer_firstname")
```

Comment: Says no such element

Comment: That was it! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
first_name_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='profile_customer_firstname']")
```

Comment: Still telling me -  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='profile_customer_firstname']"}

Comment: This is cause the web isnt load, you page_is_loaded have to find another element, like driver.find_element_by_tag_xpath("//div[@class'registration']")